# Reducing the size of Google Plus 'Add to Circles' widget

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I've searched for some time on this but have not been able to find a way to reduce the size of the widget that Google Plus provides - for example, please see the right hand column on this page - http://www.clubnetsearchmarketing.co.uk/about-us/

In this example, the widget is wider than the column width and although I managed to set overflow:hidden; I just ideally wish to reduce the size of it.

Any ideas greatly appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to change the size of the badge, aside from what you've probably already seen in the [configuration tool](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/config).  There have been a lot of requests for this however, and we (Google) are looking into options.  If and when additional customization is made available, it will likely be made available to our [Platform Preview group](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/platform-preview/) first, so I'd recommend signing up for that if you're interested in being notified when platform changes are coming.

Comment: Hi Will, ah great, thanks for clarifying and good to hear this from Google directly, will sign up to the Platform Preview group and keep an eye out for additional config options for your widgets. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this style,

```
.hYYaO {
  width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: All those classes are auto generated once you insert the widget code - what Google provide is this: <div class="right_gplus"><g:plus href="https://plus.google.com/110518643959735535940" size="badge"></g:plus></div> that's all I actually insert into the page. Thanks